# Why is my cpp array size in multiples of 4?

Tags: c++, arrays, sizeof

I am trying to create an array of size 5, and take input to fill each index, then print out each input at each index. What I am getting is the array size to be multiples of 4. So when I input 5 as the size I get 20 instead of 5. What am I missing here?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int userInput[5];
    cout << sizeof(userInput);

    // take input to fill array
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(userInput); i++) {
        cin >> userInput[i];
    }

    // print the array contents
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(userInput); i++) {
        cout << userInput[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post pictures of your code. Post your actual code as text.

Comment: An `int` is usually a 32 bit variable, hence takes 4 bytes. Therefore 5 ints take 20 bytes. You may want to have a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

Comment: @AdrianW You are assuming a byte is an octett. Mostly true nowadays, but mention that too.

Comment: Note that arrays are fairly "low level".  While they are important to know about, you probably want to build your awareness of `std::vector`, whose [.size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) gives what you would expect from a "higher-level" interface...and also lets you append and remove elements.

Answer (score 2):

This is because [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof):

> Returns size in bytes of the object representation of type.

*Not* the size of the array. (`int's` are 4 bytes long)

Answer (score 2):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof):

> **sizeof**: Returns **size in bytes** of the object representation of type.

Now, since an `int` takes `4` bytes (this is [implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398030/3160529) feature of compiler), thus an array of `int[5]` will have size `5*4=20` **bytes**.

If you want to get the size of an array, you can use (as pointed out by [Deduplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204551/deduplicator) in comments):

```
std::size( userInput );
```

Don't forget to use `#include <iterator>` in this case.

Comment: This is C++, so either use [C++17 `std::size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) or define your own.

Comment: @Deduplicator Changed my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, to get the size of a C array, use the [std::size()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) function on C++17 capable compilers:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int userInput[5];
    int arrsize = static_cast<int>(std::size(userInput));

    for (auto i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
        std::cin >> userInput[i];
    }

    for (auto i = 0; i < arrsize; i++) {
        std::cout << userInput[i];
    }
}
```

You can simplify things with a [range-based for loops](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int userInput[5];
    for (auto& el : userInput) {
        std::cin >> el;
    }
    for (auto el : userInput) {
        std::cout << el;
    }
}
```

Or replace the the C style array with a [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) wrapper:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> userInput;
    for (auto& el : userInput) {
        std::cin >> el;
    }
    for (auto el : userInput) {
        std::cout << el;
    }
}
```